# Chrome Extension Settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to make a javascript function that only runs once EVER, so that it sets a bunch of google chrome variables, does anybody know how to do that?

Here is what I have right now, but I don't think it works:

```
window.onLoad = check();

function check() {
    chrome.storage.local.get('defaultLoad', function (x) {
        if (x.defaultLoad == undefined) {
            chrome.storage.local.set({'defaultLoad': '0'}, function() {
                console.log('SearchPanel default');
                defaultLoad();
            });
        }
    });
}

function defaultLoad() {
    chrome.storage.local.set({'searchPanelOption': 'open'}, function() {
            console.log('SearchPanel default');
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({'barBackgroundOption': '#000000'}, function() {
            console.log('barBackground default');
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({'goBackgroundOption': '#000000'}, function() {
            console.log('goBackground default');
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({'barColorOption': '#ffffff'}, function() {
            console.log('barColor default');
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({'placeColorOption': '#999999'}, function() {
            console.log('placeColor default');
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({'searchEngineOption': 'google'}, function() {
            console.log('searchEngine default');
    });
}
```

That script is called at the top of the page, it should only run once ever, but I don't think it is working because I'm not getting any of the console.log outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to set default values.

define the default values in a separated file.

```
// Define default values.
var options = {
    notifyTimeout: 5,
    pageInspect: true,
    linkInspect: true,
    pushItem: false,
    notifyMode: 'margin',
};

// a method similar to jquery.ready
function initOptions(callback) {
    // get data from remote
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(data) {
        // merge remote data into local global `options`
        $.extend(options, data);
        // push them back to remote
        // maybe the extension updated and added new default values.
        chrome.storage.sync.set(options);
        // callback method to use updated options.
        callback && callback();
    });
}

// listen to remote data changes, if soem value changed
// update the global variable `options`, for example,
// you changed an option in options page and push changes to remote
// in contentscript, this got the changes and update to new value.
// you can use the updated value without a page reload.
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes) {
    for (var name in changes) {
        var change = changes[name];
        options[name] = change.newValue;
    }
});
```

in the page you want to use options, inject this script and feel free to use global variable `options`, it works in contentscript too.

```
initOptions(function() {
   doSomethingWith(options); 
});
```

I wrote an article about this, but not in English.

http://www.g2w.me/2014/08/sync-chrome-extension-options/

Comment: It would be great if you included an explanation in the answer itself (get takes default values provided), and moved your blog link to the bottom as "more info".

Comment: Ah, right. There is a shorter way to do what you're doing: if you do `chrome.storage.sync.get(options, ...)` Chrome will populate the response with default values where they are missing. No need to `extend`

Comment: I think this is probably the best way to do this, even though my function also works (as does Xan's)

Answer (score 1):

There is an event to run only upon initial install:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
  if(details.reason == "install") {
    // This code runs once
  }
});
```

However, the method [presented by greatghoul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28007884/934239) is preferable to set default options. It will overwrite any option that's not set at all with a default one, and keep the value of any option that is already set. This is better, because adding more options afterwards is as straightforward as adding a new key to default options.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this code does work, you just have to move the function call defaultLoad() out of the chrome.local.storage.set call.

```
window.onLoad = check();

function check() {
    chrome.storage.local.get('defaultLoad', function (x) {
        if (x.defaultLoad == undefined) {
            chrome.storage.local.set({'defaultLoad': '0'}, function() {
                console.log('SearchPanel default');
            });
            defaultLoad();
        }
    });
}

function defaultLoad() {
    chrome.storage.local.set({'searchPanelOption': 'open'}, function() {
            console.log('SearchPanel default');
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({'barBackgroundOption': '#000000'}, function() {
            console.log('barBackground default');
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({'goBackgroundOption': '#000000'}, function() {
            console.log('goBackground default');
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({'barColorOption': '#ffffff'}, function() {
            console.log('barColor default');
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({'placeColorOption': '#999999'}, function() {
            console.log('placeColor default');
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({'searchEngineOption': 'google'}, function() {
            console.log('searchEngine default');
    });
}
```